# Adjust scrollview when keyboard is up

Tags: android, keyboard, scrollview, android-keypad

I have an activity with a form in it. Because the form is quite long, I've used a scrollview.

The problem is that the scrollview doesn't change when the keyboard is up. The keyboard overlaps the last part of the scrollview.

How can I make sure that the keyboard is below the scrollview and the scrollview is adjusted to fit the space above it?

In the meanwhile, is there a way to make sure the buttons ‘previous’ and ‘next’ are in the keyboard as well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the application's manifest file, add the following to the desired `<activity />` --

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Comment: According to Android documentation using multiple 'state*' or 'adjust*' values has undefined results. You should use 'one state', 'one adjust' or 'one state and one adjust' values.

Answer (score 10):

You need to add **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"** in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 4):

if you use fragment, you just need to use the code to control it, like below

`context.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`

Answer (score 3):

For `ScrollView`, I like to use the following soft input mode for the `Activity` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

This works the best for me out of the other options.

Answer (score 1):

Note, if you are using CoordinatorLayout, make sure you set android:fitsSystemWindows="false" to be able to make it work for "adjustResize"

The above answers are not enough!

See this article

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/move-layout-when-keyboard-shown/

Answer (score 1):

1. `<ScrollView ... android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />`
2. Manifest
   `<activity  ... android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />` 
   it's work for me

Comment: `fitsSystemWindows` was the key in my case.