# ScrollView in Fullscreen

Tags: android, android-scrollview

i have to develope an app in fullscreen mode and now i have a formular 
with some textEdits and some buttons. If the keyboard pops up it hides
two buttons so i put everything into a scrollview:

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    tools:context="controller.RegsiterActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register_textview_firstname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/text_firstname" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/register_textedit_firstname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register_textview_lastname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/text_lastname" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/register_textedit_lastname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register_textview_email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/text_email" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/register_textedit_email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register_text_password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/text_password" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/register_textedit_password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/register_button_register"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_register" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/register_button_cancel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_cancel" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

As i said i have to run my app in fullscreen:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

But when i now run my app no scrollView appears and no scrolling is working.

How can i make the scrollView work?

Comment: consider adding `android:fillViewport="true"`

Comment: set the `scrollview` height to `match_parent`

Comment: added both. nothing changed.

Comment: can you see all content on screen

Comment: no i cant see the full content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First attribute you should probably add to the `ScrollView` is:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

When set to true, this attribute causes the scroll view’s child to expand to the height of the ScrollView if needed. When the child is taller than the ScrollView, the attribute has no effect.

Also, change the `fill_parent` layout dimensions to `match_parent` because `fill_parent` is deprecated and you can get rid of any annoying warnings.

Further, change the `layout_height` attribute of the `LinearLayout` to `match_parent` so it will resize together with the `ScrollView` on screen configuration changes such as pulling up the keyboard.

Also, similarly to @karvoynistas suggestion, you should take a look at [**`windowSoftInputMode`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) property.

You can add this property to your activity:

```
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
    ...>

    <!-- ... -->

</activity>
```

The effect of this is (according to [**`Android docs`**](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html#Respond)):

> To ensure that the system resizes your layout to the available space—which ensures that all of your layout content is accessible (even though it probably requires scrolling)

Adding the `adjustPan` value to the `windowSoftInputMode` attribute could work but not be exactly what you want since it might cause some unusual affect (read bellow).

Android Docs comparison of the two values:

**adjustResize**

> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.

**adjustPan**

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to put scrollView for that reason if the positioning is okay for you before the appearance of the keyboard.
All you have to do to avoid scrolling issues with the keyboard is to set in your manifest file, inside the specific activity declaration the following :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the application's manifest file, add to the `<activity/>` you want the following line:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422566/android-adjust-scrollview-when-keyboard-is-up) states the same issue.

Comment: the link you provided is not related to scrolling issues in fullscreen mode. and it does not solve the problem.